# Change action icon of playerNotificationManager like play/pause/stop

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I want to change action icon color of PlayerNotificationManager of ExoPlayer.
can somebody help me to change this icon?

[image]

Comment: Would you provide the code you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the icons used by PlayerNotificationManager by redefining the resources in your app's resources. Notification icons are defined in the UI module here, so (for example) you can add a drawables.xml in your app that overrides one of these:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <drawable name="exo_notification_pause">@drawable/my_pause_icon</drawable>
</resources>
```

[This issue asked on ExoPlayer github](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5372)

[Refer to this link](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/afd11de/library/ui/src/main/res/values/drawables.xml#L9)